# How to select rows in a date table? My search operation is, select rows which lies between current date and 7 days before current date?

Tags: mysql

How to select rows in a date table using MYSQL? My search operation is, select rows which lies between current date and 7 days before current date?

Comment: Oh dear. Unleash the SO rage.

Comment: Well your question is by far more explicit than your title

Answer (score 0):

`<mood sympathy="on">`

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable
where my_date_column between SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7) and CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM {{table_name}}
WHERE {{date_field}} BETWEEN {{date_7_days_ago}} AND {{date_now}}
```

Obtaining the date depends on the programming language you're working with.

Comment: he's "working with" mysql. app language doesn't need to come in to it

Comment: I meant may be he was working with some other language where he could work with dates more easily. But you're right.